# Recalling onBindViewHolder on scrolling up the Recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have list of images in my Recycler View and on scrolling down the recycler view, onBindViewHolder is called.

I want to call onBindViewHolder again when I scroll up the recycler view so that I can get the position of currently viewed image.

How to call onBindViewHolder again(on scrolling up)?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might not be the best way to figure out the currently viewed image, however you can add a scroll listener to your recycler view and whenever the dy scroll is negative you can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged, so onBindViewHolder is called again

```
   mFragmentListBinding.movieGrid.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy < 0) {
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It works but what will be the best way to figure out the currently viewed image?

Comment: How many views are visible at the same time in your layout ? because the layout manager also offer this two methods : layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() and layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

Comment: Two views are visible at same time in my layout.

Comment: so layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPostion() and layoutManager.findFirstVissibleItemPosition will give you this two visible items

Comment: when this answer solved your problem I would be very happy if you mark my answer as the solution :)